# jquery ajax post to another file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to post to PHP inside a JavaScript function and it does not seem to be working. I know it must be something simple.

Here is my code in that section, everything in that section is working but the posting to the php page

```
if (iTime == -1) {
  clearInterval(jQuery("#" + id).attr("data-interval"));
  jQuery("#" + id).find(".ctl-arcade-dlg-close").css("visibility", "visible");
  jQuery("#" + id).find("p").text("Game Ready.");

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: getContextPath() + 'levelUp.php',
    type: "post",
    type: "text",
    data: {
      "user_id": idUser,
      "game": szGamePluginDir
    }
  })
```

the php file is in same directory as this page.

Comment: "type" you used twice. Are you sure about this?

Comment: Why `type: "post", type: "text",` ?? You mean `type: post, dataType: "text"`, don't you?

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Do you get errors?

Comment: remove type: text

Comment: i had just once and it didn't seem to be posting either..  let me try again

Comment: I'm assuming you want a `POST` request? In that case, you should change `type: "post"` to `method: "POST"`. In addition, to respond to your comment on the answer posted here, if `getContextPath` is showing as undefined, make sure it exists in the proper scope, as if it's undefined the request, the script will die.

Comment: even if i try to add the direct URL in the url it does nothing.  so i am not getting errors it is just Not doing anything.  Is there a better method or maybe a GET method?i just need to ping that url with the game and user id.   i see i was corrected below and sorry  i did not know we cant answer

Comment: report any errors you get from your console when running the code. Also check your network tab to see if the request is firing. If it does, see what the HTTP response code is, and check the response from the server for any errors. Currently your code is throwing away the response from the server, regardless of whether it's successful or not, so you need to use your browser's Dev tools to debug. "It's not doing anything" is not an adequate description of the situation to allow people to help.